# How to Borsh serialize (in Typescript) arguments to interact with Aurora contract from Near?

Tags: nearprotocol, aurora-near

I have the following [contract](https://explorer.testnet.aurora.dev/address/0x202eF3618820dEaDca5017Cc585D489C585Cc2E3) deployed on Aurora testnet:

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.12 <0.9.0;

contract Counter {
  uint256 value;

  function print() public view returns (uint256) {
    return value;
  }

  function inc() public {
    value = value + 1;
  }
}
```

I want to call `inc()` from a Near account by interacting with [`aurora`](https://testnet.nearblocks.io/address/aurora) contract deployed on Near.

I am trying to Borsh serialize the arguments (using [borsh-js](https://github.com/near/borsh-js?tab=readme-ov-file#examples)) following: https://github.com/aurora-is-near/aurora-contracts-sdk/blob/main/docs/AuroraFromNear.md

As per my understanding (likely wrong) I have the following schema:

```
const functionCallArgsV2 = {
    struct: {
      contract: "string",
      value: "u8",
      input: { array: { type: "u8" } },
    },
  };

  const schema = {
    enum: [
      {
        struct: {
          FunctionCallArgsV2: functionCallArgsV2,
        },
      },
    ],
  };
```

For simplicity I want to serialize the following arguments:

```
const address = "0x202ef3618820deadca5017cc585d489c585cc2e3";
const input = "0x371303c0"; // input data for "inc"
const value = 0;

const inputBase64 = Buffer.from(input, "hex").toString("base64");
const inputEncoded = Buffer.from(inputBase64, "base64");
const data = {
    FunctionCallArgsV2: {
      contract: contractEncoded,
      value: value,
      input: inputEncoded,
    },
  };

const dataEncoded = borsh.serialize(schemaZ, data);

const functionCallResponse = await account.functionCall({
    contractId: AURORA,
    methodName: "call",
    args: dataEncoded,
  });
```

Transaction result:

```
{
  "ActionError": {
    "index": 0,
    "kind": {
      "FunctionCallError": {
        "ExecutionError": "Smart contract panicked: ERR_BORSH_DESERIALIZE"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I Borsh serialize correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contract expects the input to be of the type `CallArgs` rather than `FunctionCallArgsV2`.

See the definition of `CallArgs` [here](https://github.com/aurora-is-near/aurora-engine/blob/master/engine-types/src/parameters/engine.rs#L276-L280):

```rust
#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Clone)]
pub enum CallArgs {
    V2(FunctionCallArgsV2),
    V1(FunctionCallArgsV1),
}
```

The borsh serialization of the inner type, is not the same as of the wrapped type (they have one byte of difference). You will need to wrap your variable `data` into an enum following that signature.

Answer (score 1):

Based on feedback I have found a working schema:

```
  const functionCallArgsV2 = {
    struct: {
      contract: { array: { type: "u8", len: 20 } },
      value: { array: { type: "u8", len: 32 } },
      input: { array: { type: "u8" } },
    },
  };
  const schema = {
    enum: [
      {
        struct: {
          FunctionCallArgsV2: functionCallArgsV2,
        },
      },
    ],
  };
```